# Pg promise suddenly complain about table name is unknown

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

`console.log(columnsets.activites.forInsert)`

gives me

```
ColumnSet {
table: "accounting"."activities"
columns: [
    Column {
        name: "note"
    }
    Column {
        name: "title"
    }
    Column {
        name: "context_id"
        prop: "contextId"
    }
    Column {
        name: "created_timestamp"
        prop: "createdTimestamp"
    }
    Column {
        name: "created_by_id"
        prop: "createdById"
    }
    Column {
        name: "object_id"
        prop: "objectId"
        cnd: true
    }
]
```

}

```
pgp.helpers.insert({ contextId: user.objectId, createdById: user.objectId, createdTimestamp: now, note: null, objectId: uuid.v4(), title: MESSAGE_SUCCESS_USER_AUTHENTICATE }, columnSets.activities.forInsert)
```

I could have sworn that it was working for me until recently. I am not sure what has changed. I have table name set but why is it complaining about `Error: Table name is unknown.`

Comment: It will only complain that way, if your `columnSets.activities.forInsert` is anything but a `ColumnSet` object with table specified. Most likely it is `undefined` or something ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t i console log that out as shown :S

Comment: It wouldn't complain like that then, something else must be amiss. I suggest debugging to see what's missing ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t ill look into it. It worked before and I didnt change anything

Comment: That's the most basic functionality of type `ColumnSet` used by a lot of developers. It wouldn't just stop working on its own, something else must be going on, something not included in the code that you are showing. The only thing that would make sense is if `columnSets.activities.forInsert` didn't contain what you think when it is being passed into method `helpers.insert`.

Comment: @vitaly-t so i tried creating another file with exactly the same coloumn set and it works. I also imported that `columnSets.activities.forInsert` and console.log out this (`cs.toString() === columnSets.activities.forInsert.toString()`) and it returns true. I agree its definitely something wrong on my end but ill keep looking as this is really strange out of a sudden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158448/discussion-between-zanko-and-vitaly-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear at which point you are calling `console.log(columnsets.activites.forInsert)`, compared to the call into `helpers.insert`, but I'm guessing it happens afterwards.

There is only one reason why you would get error `Table name is unknown`, and that's when your `columnsets.activites.forInsert` doesn't contain a `ColumnSet` with table information in it.

There is no other scenario when you could get that error. You can debug the code to check that ;)

Comment: Thanks. So it was node modules problem. I am not sure exactly what causes it and why it happened in the first place. Removing node_modules was not enough to solve the problem. I ended up deleting node_modules along with package-lock.json as well. And right now everything works again.  Thanks for replying! There is no fault with this library, I was just looking for some possible error. But this node_modules problem is really odd indeed :(

Comment: @Zanko It may have been caused by using a module that uses an older version of `pg-promise`, creating a version conflict, if you are exchanging any `pg-promise` structure with it.